# Form is not submitting properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have form which is suppose to post information and upload images, when i post information the form is doing what it should do but when i browse photos it post noting, neither information nor files, can anyone help me why is it doing so? 
Actually i have 7 file fields in the form with a single one it iw working but with multiple it is not working.

```
<?php $attributes = array("name" => "project_add");
echo form_open_multipart("project/add", $attributes);?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
Project Name <span>*</span><br/>
<input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text"value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" /><br/>
<input class="form-control" name="f_lcpd" id="f_lcpd" type="checkbox" />     <label for ="">Painted Desert</label>`
Invoice <input class="form-control" name="userfile[]" id="" type="file"  />
image 1<input class="form-control" name="userfile[]" id="" type="file"  />
Image 2<input class="form-control" name="userfile[]" id="" type="file"  />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

controller function

```
public function add()
{
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (to form) when  you submit files to server. On server side, you can access these files using `$_FILES` supergloal and you can access standard POST data using `$_POST` (only if `method="POST"`)

If you want to submit multiple files, your code should looks like this:

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
```

And then, on server side (if you are not using any helper):

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
     // process image upload, e.g. if you want the size: $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$key]
}
```

You can use the above solution in conjunction with `do_upload` method in CodeIgniter.

Comment: i am following this, but still waiting for luck, i edit my question and mentioned that with single file it is ok but when i select multiple then the form do nothing.

Comment: same result, empty arrays for both `$_POST` and `$_FILLES`

Comment: i have deleted most of the code as it was hard to manage here, but i hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: Are you sure that your request is sent to **the right** controller?

Comment: as i mentioned earlier when i select a single file or do not select files then form is working properly, so request is going to right controller